# Menu deixando margem à esquerda

Tags: css, css3

Não estou conseguindo encontrar esse erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu Monitor tem 1024px e o body configurei para width: 97.65625% que dá 1000px.

O menu (`ul`) possui 7 ítens (`li's`) cada `li` com `141.7px` mais `8 bordas` de `1px` cada dão `999,9 pixels`. Ou seja, cabem em `1000px`. => `(141.7 * 7) + 8 = 999,9`

Tenho um menu na página abaixo que não chega pro canto esquerdo de jeito nenhum. Ele insiste em dar uma `margem` de uns `50px`.

Mas tanto o que está acima dele quanto abaixo, estao corretos.

Parece que embora esteja usando `list-style: none` na `ul`, e os marcadores realmente sumiram, esses marcadores ainda estão lá ocupando seu lugar. Só pode.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
    /* CSS Document */
    * {
     margin: auto;
    }
    
    body { 
     width: 97.65625%;  /* 1000 px de 1024px */
    }
    
    ul {
     list-style:none;
    }
    
    .liMenu {
     float:left;
     width:141.7px;
     border-left: #000 1px solid;
     text-align:center;
    }
    
    .liMenu:last-child {
     border-right: #000 1px solid;
    }
```

```html
<ul class="ulMenu">
  <li  class="liMenu">Home</li>
  <li  class="liMenu">Cotato</li>
  <li  class="liMenu">Imóveis</li>
  <li  class="liMenu">Lançamentos</li>
  <li  class="liMenu">Oportunidades</li>
  <li  class="liMenu">Quem somos</li>
  <li  class="liMenu">Serviços</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Tem definido `margin: auto;` para todos os elementos, conforme escrito logo no início do CSS. Experimente colocar `margin:0;`. Se resultar, é disso.

Comment: era isso mesmo. Obrigado!